# laravel sum and list in one sql?

Tags: sql, laravel

I have kind of data

```
order:
id      name         date       payment
----------------------------------------
1       Amy's      2019-1-15      Cash                
2       Hotel1's   2019-1-18      Visa                       

orderdetail:
id       orderid    food      number                            
----------------------------------------------
1           1         1          3            
2           1         2          1            
3           1         3          3            
4           1         4          2            
5           2         1          1            
6           2         3          1            

food:
food     name         fee            
-------------------------------------------
1        Apple          4                         
2        Beef          15                   
3        Orange         3                 
4        Apple pie      7
```

I obtained this data using this sql query(but not fulfill my result)

```
Order::query()
->select('order.name', 'order.date', 'orderdetail.number*food.fee as totalcost', 'order.payment')
->leftJoin('orderdetail', 'Order.id', '=', 'orderdetail.orderid')
->leftJoin('food', 'order.food', '=', 'food.id')
->get();
```

I want to get the result like:

```
    order name/food name       date       totalcost   payment
-------------------------------------------------------------
order1-->  Amy's             2019-1-15        50         Cash
           Apple             2019-1-15        12         Cash
           Beef              2019-1-15        15         Cash
           Orange            2019-1-15         9         Cash
           Apple pie         2019-1-15        14         Cash
order2-->  Hotel1's          2019-1-18         7         Visa
           Apple             2019-1-18         4         Visa
           Orange            2019-1-18         3         Visa
```

and i only want this result from one sql. It's a better way to get my result?

Comment: Your result set is confusing. I don't think it'd be possible to achieve this with a single SQL.